# Alternative for AlarmManager.setExact android api 18 and less

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am developing an android app that uses AlarmManager.
The app has to be very accurate, but AlarmManager.setExact is available only from API 19 (Android Kitkat), and I have an old phone that its android version is 4 (API 16).
I tried using a service, but it stops when I lock the phone.
I need an alternative that works for APIs below 19.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Depending on your definition of "very accurate", nothing on Android is "very accurate" with respect to timing.

Comment: @CommonsWare Very accurate means that the alarm will start in the second I want it to start

Comment: That won't happen with Doze mode and app standby on Android 6.0+. About the only thing that is fairly accurate (though perhaps not to the second) and reliable is `setAlarmClock()` on `AlarmManager`, and from the user's standpoint, that really should be reserved for alarm clock apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare setAlarmClock is from android lollipop

Comment: Agreed. And, prior to Android 6.0, `set()`/`setExact()` were decent, though not necessarily down to the second, as there are lots of things going on in the device and it may take a moment to get around to forking a process for you and giving you control.

Comment: @CommonsWare read my question again

Comment: You have not changed your question. Most likely, you should not be using Android for your project. For example, you might use a real-time OS (RTOS) on suitable hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Just set().  Before API 19, set was an exact set.  setExact was added when set was made inexact.

Comment: No, when I use set() the alarm starts very late

Comment: Like said above, nothing is exact on Android.  Especially nothing to the second like you want.  Android optimizes more for battery than that.

Comment: But what is your targetSDK set to?  That's what controls the behavior of set.  If targetSDK>=19, set is inexact.  If targetSDK<19, set is exact.  This is independent of what the API level of the device is.  See:  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html

Comment: The alarm still starts late

Comment: You aren't going to get exact second wakeups.  Android just doesn't support it.

Comment: The alarm starts late in more than a minute

Comment: Then use a newer version of the OS.  What you want, you can't get reliably.